# Adding standard (open, save, print) buttons to Ribbon

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons, vsto, ribbon

Is there a way to automatically add standard buttons like New, Open, Save, Print etc. to WPF Ribbon control, or at least get those images? This can easily be done in VSTO solutions, where you can use `OfficeImageID` property (string type) to use built-in Office icons for your buttons (a list of all Office icon IDs is available from Microsoft too), but the desktop version of the control doesn't seem to have this property.

Even the good old ToolStrip (WinForms) provides a command "Insert Standard Items" in the designer context menu. Is there any better option than manually searching for each image over the Internet and then applying them to my buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement all the functionality on your own. The Office Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) and Windows UI (the Ribbon WPF in your case) are entirely different things.